# Functions and for loops: first time messing around with it and now it's just a mess

Tags: c++, for-loop

So...this is my first time messing around with functions and almost never worked with `for` either and I wanted to create a function that printed hello as many times as the parameter (`n`) said.

```
#include <iostream>
int say_hello(int n){
    for(int n, int t=0; t!=n; t++){
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main(){
    say_hello(5);
    return 0;
}
```

But I seem to have done something horribly wrong because of all these errors.

- error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
- error: expected ';' before 'int'
- warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
- error: expected ')' before ';' token
- error: 't' was not declared in this scope
- error: expected ';' before ')' token
- warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

I want to learn C++ properly and at least try to not get into too many bad habits, any advice on sites or beginner challenges?

Comment: Read a good book like "C++ Primer 5th Edition" before cluelessly diving into the language. It will teach you all the basics

Comment: Compile - Look a first error - fix that. Repeat

Comment: Iknow I could have used a "while" loop but i want to learn "for" too.

Comment: Try HackerRank with C++ exercise.

Comment: The variable `n` is already declared, you don't need to do it again. And the first part of the `for` loop is a normal declaration. If you had, on a line by itself, something like `int n, int t;` you would not expect that to work would you?

Comment: "Deitel & Deitel, C++ How to Program" is good for beginners too.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Learning "properly" usually involves at least one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Online tutorials are littered with the bad habits you want to avoid.

Comment: @EdHeal should be "Look at first error or first warning"? (fix errors first, then warnings, only then stop)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem boils down to replacing

`for(int n, int t=0; t!=n; t++){`

with

`for(int t=0; t!=n; t++){`

You don't need to redeclare `n` (as it's a function *parameter*), which also fixes the syntax error in the `for` loop. That syntax error is the cause of all the compiler diagnostics. More often than not, the first compiler diagnostic is the one you should concentrate on.

Also, don't forget to return a value from `say_hello`, or make it a `void` return type.

Comment: Thanks makes alot more sense now

Comment: You must change `t!=n` to `t<n` too, else you will get one extra "hello"

Comment: @Mischo5500: Good spot, and is in the question spec too. Consider putting it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the function. You shall not declare the variable `n` in the `for` statement that hides the parameter.

```
int say_hello(int n){
    for(int n, int t=0; t!=n; t++){
        ^^^^^^
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Also `t` is not good name for an index in a loop. It would be better to use for example the name `i`.

Also the function is unsafe because the argument passed to the function can be a negative number.

And the function returns nothing though it has return type `int`. Thus the function has undefined behavior.

So a more correct function definition can look like

```
void say_hello( unsigned int n )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or it can return reference to the stream that will allow to chain the function with other functions.

For example

```
std::ostream & say_hello( unsigned int n, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != n; i++ )
    {
        os << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

In fact the local variable `i` is not used in the body of the for statement. So it can be removed. In this case you can use a while loop instead of the for loop. For example

```
std::ostream & say_hello( unsigned int n, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    while ( n-- )
    {
        os << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: the while could be a for loop: `for(;n>0;--n)`

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your `for` statement this way:

```
// n cannot be negative since we are counting from 0
// hence we have an unsigned int argument
int say_hello(unsigned int n) { 
    for(unsigned int t=0; t<n; t++) { // t ranges from 0 to n-1 i.e. loop executes n times
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
}
```